# input fields on different form_tag generates same tag Id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datepicker

I have two form_tag that contains datepicker field in a single HTML file.
The contents are the almost identical only that time_start is displayed in the first form
while time_end is displayed in the second form.

```
<%= form_tag sample_path, method: :get do %>
  <%= text_field_tag "time_start", nil, class: "datepicker" %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag "time_end", nil %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag "other_info", nil %>
  ...
  <%= submit_tag "Submit"%>
<% end %>
...

<%= form_tag sample_path, method: :get do %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag "time_start", nil %>
  <%= text_field_tag "time_end", nil, class: "datepicker" %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag "other_info", nil %>
  ...
  <%= submit_tag "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

However, when I select a date in time_end, the form is submitted even though the submit button is not pressed.

I am guessing because the input fields generated in the HTML has the same id.

```
<form action="sample" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="time_start" id="time_start" class="datepicker hasDatepicker">
  <input type="hidden" name="time_end" id="time_end">
  <input type="hidden" name="other_info" id="other_info">
  ...
  <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Submit" data-disable-with="Submit">
</form>
...
<form action="sample" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="get">
  <input type="hidden" name="time_start" id="time_start">
  <input type="text" name="time_end" id="time_end" class="datepicker hasDatepicker">
  <input type="hidden" name="other_info" id="other_info">
  ...
  <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Submit" data-disable-with="Submit">
</form>
```

I added [index](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#using-form-helpers) or [namespace](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for) options to a form_tag, but it seems it is not applicable with form_tag.

```
<%= form_tag sample_path, {index: 'group_01', method: :get} do %>
...
<%= form_tag sample_path, {namespace: 'group_02',method: :get} do %>
...
```

Is there any way to distinguish the elements IDs in each form_tag?

Answer (score 1):

You're right, `form_tag` does not allow the methods you mentioned.

In this case, since you're using `hidden_field_tag`, you can pass 3 options, as stated [here in the documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/hidden_field_tag).

So you'll need to manually add the id attribute to each of the fields, like so:

```
 <%= hidden_field_tag "other_info", nil, time_start: "custom_id" %>
```

However, the issue you're describing is not related to the IDs themselves, but to the plugin you're using with Javascript.